# Why does sbt fail with NoClassDefFoundError: play/Play$ in Play 2.2.x projects after sbt compile in Play 2.3 project?

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

Once I run 'sbt compile' on a 2.3 play project, I can't use 'sbt compile' to compile any Play 2.2.x projects anymore. This is the error when I run sbt command.

```
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/macbookpro/playproject/project
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/Play$
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Comment: Would you mind adding `sbt about` and the entire session to the question?

Comment: See my answer to [Can't Run Activator Template projects Activator UI Failed to load SBT configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155681/cant-run-activator-template-projects-activator-ui-failed-to-load-sbt-configurat/34347454#34347454).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I just had this same issue. In my case I was using Play 2.4, but it's probably the same cause. I had run activator ui in my project directory accidentally. It created a `project/play-fork-run.sbt` file which is for activator support, but was preventing sbt from working directly. Deleting that file cleared up the issue and I can now use sbt again.

Comment: Removed my comment as it was not going to help anything.  I up-voted your post @tim  Thanks!  Verified it works.

Comment: You save my day, Tim:)

Answer (score 5):

Try updating  play-fork-run.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-fork-run-plugin" % "2.3.8")
```

update to

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-fork-run-plugin" % "2.4.0")
```

Then project will be able to build.

Answer (score 4):

That's interesting issue since it works for me (TM) on Mac OS X 10.9.3 with Java 7.

I downloaded the versions of Play - the latest 2.3.1 and the latest in 2.2.x stream - 2.2.3. With these two versions I've used `activator` (2.3.1) to create the web application and `play` for 2.2.3. Both worked well.

When I executed `sbt compile` in 2.3.1 and then 2.2.3, both commands worked fine, too. It took me some time to have all the dependencies downloaded, but at the end the results were as follows:

```
jacek:~/sandbox/play231-app
$ sbt compile
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/play231-app/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/play231-app/project/}play231-app-build...
...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 5 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /Users/jacek/sandbox/play231-app/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] 'compiler-interface' not yet compiled for Scala 2.11.1. Compiling...
[info]   Compilation completed in 14.895 s
[success] Total time: 200 s, completed Jun 25, 2014 1:00:18 PM
```

And for 2.2.3:

```
jacek:~/sandbox/play223-app
$ sbt compile
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/play223-app/project
[info] Set current project to play223-app (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/play223-app/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/play223-app/}play223-app...
...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 5 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /Users/jacek/sandbox/play223-app/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] 'compiler-interface' not yet compiled for Scala 2.10.3. Compiling...
[info]   Compilation completed in 19.626 s
[success] Total time: 45 s, completed Jun 25, 2014 3:15:34 PM
```

I'm using sbt 0.13.5 installed using homebrew.

```
$ sbt --version
sbt launcher version 0.13.5

$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

Play 2.3 app is supposed to be built using activator, to ensure proper sbt configuration. Best

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Make sure that you are using the java-8 version.
I was using java-7, changing to java-8 fixed my problem.