# Failed to load sbt configuration Play-Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

i was trying to make a new project with play-scala in my activator, but i keep getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/Play$
Use 'last' for the full log.
Failed to load project.
```

Comment: See my answer to [Can't Run Activator Template projects Activator UI Failed to load SBT configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155681/cant-run-activator-template-projects-activator-ui-failed-to-load-sbt-configurat/34347454#34347454).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
[Why does sbt fail with NoClassDefFoundError: play/Play$ in Play 2.2.x projects after sbt compile in Play 2.3 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397285/why-does-sbt-fail-with-noclassdeffounderror-play-play-in-play-2-2-x-projects-a)

The project/play-fork-run.sbt file in the your-project-name\project folder needs to be removed if you tried the entire process through the "activator ui" web interface.